# Does MUPDF Reads ASCII? and if not, I would like to know how does he handle the English format as I want to make him handle Arabic format?

Tags: android, search, ascii, arabic, mupdf

I am working on Android App that uses MUPDF reader to read pdf files, these pdf files contain Arabic letters and I want to use the search inside the mupdf to search for these Arabic letters, it only can find one letter but not a complete word, I tried to know if mupdf reads using ascii but I couldn't, so is there any methodology to make the mupdf finds whole Arabic words?

Answer (score 1):

I was using Mupdf version 1.2, it was not supporting LTR and RTL but after I have downloaded version 1.3 which was released in 15-8 I can now write any Arabic word in reversed order and the Mupdf will finds it.
you can find the latest version here: http://www.mupdf.com/download/

Comment: Do you have any idea how to read RTL pdf in mupdf 1.3? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Left-to-right and right-to-left searching ought to work, if it doesn't then I suggest you open a bug report at bugs.ghostscript.com and attach a file where the search doesn't work. The simplest file you can manage would be appreciated.

Comment: I tried LTR and RTL before, unfortunately it didn't solve it and I tried to make a report but I found this bug report: https://code.google.com/p/sumatrapdf/issues/detail?id=2221.
they said "If you can make SumatraPDF/MuPDF treat the different forms as equals (like ignoring accents in other languages), much can be solved."

Comment: I doubt this is readily amenable to solution, as the three different forms of each glyph (initial, medial, terminal) I think have different Unicode values. MuPDF uses Unicode to search with, I believe, so I suspect that you need to ensure that the search string has the same glyphs in the same order (and all the same glyphs) in order to match words. Additionally I think kashidas will present a problem, since (as I understand it) these are simply 'spacing' glyphs and do not contribute to the word meaning, so need to be ignored. Essentially you are going to need a complete custom Arabic search.